# Link Labels c# - displaying a list of them

Tags: c#, linklabel

I am trying to add a list of linked lables to a listview. I amd doing so like this

```
        foreach (String s in values)
        {
            LinkLabel label = new LinkLabel();
            label.Text = s;
            txtBox.Controls.Add(label);
        }
    }
```

It keeps adding just one item to the listbox even tho there are more. Any ideas?

ps) i can tell there are more items from adding a breakbpoint and using console.writeline when iterating

Thanks

Comment: yes, sorry should have changed the variable name back as i started with a textbox, im just mocking something up at the moment. Sorry

Comment: No idea for me. This snippet of code looks fine to me. Maybe you should seek the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Why should one adding `LinkLabel` instances to a `ListBox`?!?

Comment: This isn't what a `ListView`/`ListBox` is designed for...

Comment: so what should i add a link label too, directly to a form?

Comment: @tom: How about a `Panel`? Or better yet, a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` that handles the layout of its child controls automatically.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Can you put that as an answer so i can accept it please. I used the FlowLayoutPanel. Many thanks

Comment: @Tom: Done. Glad to see you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `ListView` or `ListBox` controls are really designed to host child controls.

If that's what you need, then you should be using a container control, such as a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx). I recommend using either a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) that can automatically manage the layout of its child controls.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.
What you are doing is adding control to listitem and not items.

Thus, when you check => txtbox.Items.Count = 0; and txtbox.Controls.Count = 2
after the for loop.