# How to show scroll button in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, scroll

I am adding user control to listbox. Everything works fine but i have a problem that when i add 10 user controls then i am expecting that listbox should show scroll so that i can select items at the end of listbox but this never happens even after setting show scroll property to true.

here is my code

```
UserControl1 button = new UserControl1();

button.Location = new Point(10, 100 * i + 10);
button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(560, 59);
button.MessageUsername = "Wao this is great";
listBox1.Controls.Add(button);
```

I am open to ideas

here is the picture you can see that there is no scroll [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712191/link-labels-c-displaying-a-list-of-them/4712515#4712515) get the idea that a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) is a container control? That's not what a `ListBox` is for, it's not designed to hold child controls added with the `Controls.Add` method. You're supposed to add (and otherwise manage) the items it displays using its aptly-named [`Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx).

There's no scroll bars visible because you've just overlaid each of the child controls on top of one another. The `ListBox` itself doesn't know about them, so it doesn't know that it needs to scroll them.

You should be using some type of panel control, either the [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) control itself, or better yet one that will manage layout for you automatically. Investigate the [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) or [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). All of those controls have an [`AutoScroll` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) you can set to "True" that will automatically show the scrollbars whenever their contents exceed the visible client area.

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel was the thing i was looking for.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ListBox is not a container! 
For customize listbox items you should use ownerdraw draw mode. But in you case it wouldn't be right. As variant I can suggest you to use simple panel and isolated scroll box which would move (scroll) each control on panel