# Is there any way to place multiple links in the LinkLabel control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to place multiple links in the `LinkLabel` control in Windows Forms?

If I just set it like this

```
this.linkLabel.Text = "";
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    this.linkLabel.Text += url + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

it merges it into one link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link Labels c# - displaying a list of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712191/link-labels-c-sharp-displaying-a-list-of-them)

Comment: @MethodMan This is not a duplicate of that question. That question has to do with adding multiple `LinkLabel` controls to another control. This has to do with adding multiple links to a single `LinkLabel`, something not addressed anywhere in the linked question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, though there isn't a way that I can tell to do it directly from the designer, but it is easy to manage via code:

```
var linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
linkLabel.Text = "(Link 1) and (Link 2)";
linkLabel.Links.Add(1, 6, "Link data 1");
linkLabel.Links.Add(14, 6, "Link data 2");
linkLabel.LinkClicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Link.LinkData);
```

Basically, the [Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection on the label can host a bunch of links in the `LinkLabel`. The `LinkClicked` event contains a reference to the specific link that was clicked so you can access the link data you associated with the link, among other things.

The designer only exposes a `LinkArea` property which defaults to include all of the text of the `LinkLabel`. The first `Link` you add to the `Links` collection will automatically change the `LinkArea` property to reflect the first link in the collection.

Something a little closer to what you're asking would look like this:

```
var addresses = new List<string> {
    "http://www.example.com/page1",
    "http://www.example.com/page2",
    "http://www.example.com/page3",
};

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var links = new List<LinkLabel.Link>(); 

foreach (var address  in addresses)
{
    if (stringBuilder.Length > 0) stringBuilder.AppendLine();

    // We cannot add the new LinkLabel.Link to the LinkLabel yet because
    // there is no text in the label yet, so the label will complain about
    // the link location being out of range. So we'll temporarily store
    // the links in a collection and add them later.
    links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(stringBuilder.Length, address.Length, address));        
    stringBuilder.Append(address);
}

var linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
// We must set the text before we add the links.
linkLabel.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
foreach (var link in links)
{
    linkLabel.Links.Add(link);
}
linkLabel.AutoSize = true;
linkLabel.LinkClicked += (s, e) => {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((string)e.Link.LinkData);
};
```

I'm attaching the URL itself as the `LinkData` to the link's I'm creating in the loop so I can extract it out as a string when the `LinkClicked` event is fired.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your solution doesn't work when addresses contains, for example, the following URLs -- `"http://www.example/1"`, `"http://www.example/1/2"` and `"http://www.example/1/3"`. What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: I thought of that right after I posted, but didn't have access to a computer to change my answer. Basically, you need to just build your text yourself using a StringBuilder and track the location of the links as you add them. See the modified code sample.